# Reorder elements of ListView by dragging

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, drag-and-drop, android-arrayadapter

I see it done a lot lately on android: I can drag an item in a listView to another position in the list. But I can't seem to find any example code. Does anyone have some example code they don't mind sharing. I have been reading http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html, but I am not making much progress.

**Complication**

So I find what seems to be a simple way to accomplish the drag-sort (http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html). But my child views are clickable themselves, and that seem to block the parent ListView from seeing my drag events. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Thanks for the link, the question, and the upvote...I ended up abandoning the drag-drop idea because I wanted my rows to have a long-press context menu...but I'll follow this issue for future use as I know I'll want to implement this.

Answer (score 4):

The bauerca listview is a possibility...[this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813882/bauerca-drag-sort-listview-simple-example) deals with the fact that it is somewhat complicated, and offers a library to consolidate things; the Git source code [can be found here](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview). Good Luck, it worked for me with some difficulty!