# DragSortListView- Android Studio not recognizing dropListener and removeListener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to use https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview to incorporate drag and drop resorting for an app I am trying to write.  I am not sure if my error is in how I imported DragSortListView or in my code.

I originally imported the library by just using maven central and adding the dependency compile 'asia.itivity.android:drag-sort-listview:1.0' to my build.gradle for module:app. The problem I am having is that in my code which I will list below when I call listItems.setDropListener(onDrop)and        listItems.setRemoveListener(onRemove) Android Studio cannot resolve symbols '.setDropListener' and 'setRemovelistener but it does recognize everything else pertaining to the drag-sort listview.  I followed this example [Bauerca drag-sort-listview simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813882/bauerca-drag-sort-listview-simple-example) as well as the examples in the repository itself.

I changed Main Activity extends ActionBarActivity to extends ListActivity which made no difference. I cloned the git repository https://github.com/JayH5/drag-sort-listview to a folder on my computer using the git gui I installed on my computer (this is all brand new to me) and then using Android Studio I added /demo and /library as modules to my project and added library as a dependecy to my main module app but I still get the error.  I also tried to add demo as a dependency but got an error so I removed that dependency.  I really appreciate any help! i initially tried to use ListViewAnimations library but could't get that to work either (stableId issues).

Thanks so much! Taryn

```js
package dtcj.bandtasker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    //create list of trigger phrases
    private ArrayList<String> items;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;


    private DragSortListView.DropListener onDrop = new DragSortListView.DropListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void drop(int from, int to)
        {
            if (from != to)
            {
                String item = itemsAdapter.getItem(from);
                itemsAdapter.remove(item);
                itemsAdapter.insert(item, to);
            }
        }
    };

    private DragSortListView.RemoveListener onRemove = new DragSortListView.RemoveListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void remove(int which)
        {
            String item = itemsAdapter.getItem(which);
            itemsAdapter.remove(item);
        }
    };


    @Override
    public DragSortListView getListView() {
        return (DragSortListView) super.getListView();
    }
    //Methods to read and write user entered items to the data file

    private void readItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "triggers.txt");
        try {
            items = new ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            items = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }

    private void writeItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "triggers.txt");
        try {
            FileUtils.writeLines(todoFile, items);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        items = new ArrayList<String>(8);
        readItems();
        itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                items);
        listItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);}
        DragSortListView listItems = (DragSortListView) getListView();
    //Problem is here
        listItems.setDropListener(onDrop);
        listItems.setRemoveListener(onRemove);
    //TO DO
    // Action Bar- "How to use", About


    //Add phrases to list
    public void onAddItem(View v) {
        //check that there are fewer than 8 trigger phrases in the array
        if (items.size() <= 7){
            EditText getNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.getNewItem);
            String itemText = getNewItem.getText().toString();
            itemsAdapter.add(itemText);
            getNewItem.setText("");
            writeItems();}
        else{
            //Warn user they have reached maximum number of Trigger Phrases
            // Creating alert Dialog with one Button

            final AlertDialog.Builder maxAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            maxAlert.setMessage("Sorry! Eight is the maximum number of trigger phrases. Please delete a phrase before adding a new one.")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //do things

                        }
                    });

            // Showing Alert Message
            maxAlert.show();


        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

build.gradle for module:app

```js
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dtcj.bandtasker"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile files('libs/microsoft-band-1.3.10622.3.jar')
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile project(':library')
}
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':demo', ':library'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was an Android studio bug.  I tried to Invalidate Cache/Restart, deleting settings.gradle, and various suggestions I found on stack overflow.  In the end I just opened a new studio project and copied the example code I linked to above and altered variable names and layout as needed and used maven central to add the library as a dependency. The methods were not flagged by Android Studio in the new project.