# How to use DragSortListView

Tags: android

The use of simple DragSortListView? Because I contact with android not too long, making the Demo on the don't understand. Can you give me a simple Demo? Don't be too complicated, beginners can read the best, thank you

Comment: Try this link which is helpful, but also try with self.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813882/bauerca-drag-sort-listview-simple-example

Answer (score 0):

Consider using RecyclerView, no more need for 3rd libraries,

[Check out all example by using simple google search](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=recyclerview%20drag%20and%20drop%20example)

Comment: Thank you very much, you are my first a friend, came to Stack Overflow can the focus on each other?